# Pharo: customizing smart characters

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

The checkbox "Smart Characters" in "Code Completion" section of Settings Browser does (at least) two things:

1) It doubles some characters when typed: ', ", (, [, {

2) It enables that I can select a piece of code, press `(` (i.e. `Shift+9`), and the selected code becomes surrounded by parentheses: `()`. I also can remove parentheses by pressing `(` again. I also can do this with `[]` by pressing `[` and with `{}` by pressing `{`, i.e. `Shift+[`.

I do not like the first of these things so I want to disable it, but I like the second thing and want to keep it. How can I achieve this? Turning off the checkbox will disable both.

P.S. I know that when the checkbox is off, adding/removing parentheses works by `Cmd+Shift+9` (which is less convenient than `Shift+9`) and that `Cmd+[` works for `[]`, although I do not know any working shortcut for adding/removing `{}` when the checkbox is off.

Answer (score 3):

The setting is called "Smart Characters", which should give you a clue as to where to look. Open a Finder, type in `smartCharacters`, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You should see some partial matches as well as an exact match for `NECController` and `NECPreferences class` (and the former just calls the latter). If you investigate the classes involved a bit, you'll see that `smartCharacters` stores a boolean, and that `smartCharactersMapping` returns a dictionary mapping some characters to their "counterparts", i.e. `$[` to `$]` and so on. Now look at senders of `smartCharactersMapping`, and you'll see where it's being called from.

The caller you're most likely interested in would be `NECController>>smartCharacterWithEvent`. So put a breakpoint in that very ugly method to see what it does. You don't care about the first two cases (the editor having a selection and there not being a smart mapping), since you want to prevent the second matching character from being inserted. So the interesting bit for you is this bit:

```
self newSmartCharacterInsertionStringForLeft: char right: opposite
```

The method only has one implementor and that one sender, so it should be safe to comment out the original method and just return the "left" character, i.e.:

```
newSmartCharacterInsertionStringForLeft: left right: right
    ^String with: left
```

In other words, instead of creating a string with the left and right characters, and possibly spaces between them, just return a new string with the single character you typed. Might not be the most elegant way of solving this, but it should work, and should show you how to solve similar problems in the future.

(Ideally, you'll find a better solution, post it here as an alternate answer, and contribute it to the Pharo codebase - Pharo is open source, after all.)

Comment: Thanks. The substitution you proposed
`newSmartCharacterInsertionStringForLeft: left right: right
    ^String with: left`
makes the method's name misleading, so instead of changing this method's implementation I commented out the call of this method (`self newSmartCharacterInsertionStringForLeft: char right: opposite`), substituting it with just `String with: char`.

<see next comment>

Comment: But that still was too deep (a whole bunch of code that lead to that point became useless but was still being executed), so I climbed up and commented out the whole second part of `smartCharacterWithEvent:` method, starting at `opposite :=`, through the end, and substituted it with `^nil`.

Comment: Why on earth I cannot edit my comment after 5 minutes? :(      

And 600 characters per comment limitation seems too restrictive...

And how can I insert a line break here?

Comment: Please see [comment privilege details](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to find out more about how comments work. There are [reasons why comments have an edit time limit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78573/183627), and, as I said in my answer, you could post your solution in an alternate answer.